Why the form property not working on MUI button as like html button field?
I need to submit the form with react hook form with zod validation. But in my condition, the submit button was outside of the form tag. So I used the id form method. ( please sudjust any other method as well. )
<form onSubmit={methods.handleSubmit(onSubmit)} id="sequenceForm">
   <label htmlFor="startDate">Start Date</label>
   <DatePickers name="startDate" id="startDate" />
</form>

    <button
    form="sequenceForm"
    onClick={() => {
    setDialogOpen(false);
     }}
    >
    Save
    </button>

>! not working
    <Button
    form="sequenceForm"
    onClick={() => {
    setDialogOpen(false);
     }}
     >
     Save
    </Button>

I need to use MUI button with form props as like as button field.

you could have the button call your own form submit function.  for example:
const formRef = useRef(null);
const handleClickSubmit = () => {
    if (formRef && formRef.current){
        setDialogOpen(false);
        formRef.current.submit();
    }
}
return (
    <form ref={formRef} onSubmit={methods.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>{
        /* your form */}
    </form>
    <Button onClick={handleClickSubmit}>Save</Button>
)

i'm not 100% sure that is how you submit the form using a ref, but hopefully the idea itself is helpful.

This is not working as I expected. It's refreshing the whole page. not even check the validation. @sparkJ

Thanks for giving an idea about this.

const formRef = useRef(null);
formRef.current.requestSubmit();

submit with requestSubmit works for me.
